# Stored procedure performance advice

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a complex stored procedure requirement that returns about 100000 rows, i need to return all rows so the data can be exported, however the query takes a long time to execute, is there any chance you could look over the query and provide any performance improvements as i have tried many different ideas? It is really the calls to get the question that slow things up i think?

Any tips greatly appreciated

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Orders_GetItems]

   @DateType int,
   @DateFrom datetime,
   @DateTo datetime,
   @PaymentType int,
   @PaymentReceived int,
   @ProductsList nvarchar(2000) = '',
   @StartRowIndex int,
   @MaximumRows int,
@VirtualCount int output

AS
-- The number of rows affected by the different commands
-- does not interest the application, so turn NOCOUNT ON
SET NOCOUNT ON

-- Determine the first record and last record 
DECLARE @FirstRec int, @LastRec int

SELECT @FirstRec = (@StartRowIndex - 1) * @MaximumRows
SELECT @LastRec = (@StartRowIndex * @MaximumRows + 1);

SELECT @VirtualCount = count(*)
from qdos_OrderPayments p 
left join qdos_PaymentTypes pt on p.PaymentTypeID = pt.PaymentTypeID
inner join qdos_orders o on p.OrderID = o.OrderID
inner join sf_user_profile_link pl on o.customerid = pl.user_id
inner join sf_sitefinity_profile sp on pl.profile_id = sp.id
left join qdos_WhiteLabels wl on wl.WhiteLabelID = sp.white_label_id
left join qdos_Coupons c on o.CouponID = c.CouponID
where 
o.ShopID = 1  
and ((@DateType = 1 and  p.PaymentAddedDate >=@DateFrom and p.PaymentAddedDate <=Dateadd(n,-1,Dateadd(d,1,@DateTo))) or
 (@DateType = 2 and  p.PaymentReceivedDate >=@DateFrom and p.PaymentReceivedDate <=Dateadd(n,-1,Dateadd(d,1,@DateTo))))
 and (@PaymentType = -1 or (@PaymentType = 1 and p.PaymentTypeID IN (1,2,3,4)) or (@PaymentType = 2 and p.PaymentTypeID IN (5,6)) )
 and  (@PaymentReceived = -1 or (@PaymentReceived = 0 and p.PaymentReceivedDate IS Null or (@PaymentReceived = 1 and p.PaymentReceivedDate IS Not Null)))
  and (@ProductsList = '' or o.ProductID in (Select IntValue from dbo.CsvToInt(@ProductsList)))


SELECT top(@MaximumRows) p.PaymentID, p.OrderID, o.ProductID, o.GroupRef, sp.account_number as AccountNumber, o.CompanyName, sp.Address1, sp.Address2, sp.City, sp.Postcode, 
o.Trade, o.SubTrade, o.PolicyNum, isnull(NULLIF(o.MultiProductTitle,''), o.ProductTitle)  as OrderTitle, o.IndemnityLevel, o.PolicyStartDate, o.PolicyExpiryDate,
o.ApplicationDate, o.PaymentDate, o.TotalPrice, (o.TotalPrice - (select  SUM(pay.PaymentAmount) from qdos_OrderPayments pay where pay.PaymentReceivedDate is not null and pay.OrderID = p.OrderID)) AS  TotalBalanceOutstanding,
pt.Type AS PaymentType, p.PaymentAddedDate, p.PaymentReceivedDate,
TotalVAT = ((o.TotalPrice ) - ((o.TotalPrice) / ((100 + o.VATRate) / 100))),
TotalIPT = ((o.TotalPrice - o.IPTExcemptAmount) - ((o.TotalPrice - o.IPTExcemptAmount) / ((100 + o.IPTRate) / 100))),
TotalNET = (o.TotalPrice - ((o.TotalPrice ) - ((o.TotalPrice) / ((100 + o.VATRate) / 100))) - ((o.TotalPrice - o.IPTExcemptAmount) - ((o.TotalPrice - o.IPTExcemptAmount) / ((100 + o.IPTRate) / 100)))),
p.PaymentAmount,
PublicLiabilityPrice = (case(o.ProductID) WHEN 4 then (p.PaymentAmount / 100) * (100 - ((select  sum(UnitCost) from qdos_OrderExtras e where e.OrderID = p.OrderID) / o.TotalPrice) * 100) end),
EmployersLiabilityPrice = (case(o.ProductID) WHEN 4 then (p.PaymentAmount / 100) * ((select  sum(UnitCost) from qdos_OrderExtras e where e.OrderID = p.OrderID) / o.TotalPrice) * 100 end),
CoverPastWork = (case(o.ProductID) WHEN 3 then (select max(ExtraOption) from qdos_OrderExtras e where e.ProductID = 12 and e.OrderID = p.OrderID) end),
ERNNumber = (select max(Response) from qdos_OrderQuestions q where q.QuestionID = 79 and q.OrderID = p.OrderID),
NameOfRig = (select max(Response) from qdos_OrderQuestions q where q.QuestionID = 153 and q.OrderID = p.OrderID),
GadgetDetails = (case(o.ProductID) WHEN 65 then
(select max(Response) from qdos_OrderQuestions q where q.QuestionID = 173 and q.OrderID = p.OrderID)  + ' ' + (select max(Response) from qdos_OrderQuestions q where q.QuestionID = 177 and q.OrderID = p.OrderID) + ' ' + (select max(Response) from qdos_OrderQuestions q where q.QuestionID = 172 and q.OrderID = p.OrderID)  + ' | ' +
(select max(Response) from qdos_OrderQuestions q where q.QuestionID = 179 and q.OrderID = p.OrderID)  + ' ' + (select max(Response) from qdos_OrderQuestions q where q.QuestionID = 180 and q.OrderID = p.OrderID) + ' ' + (select max(Response) from qdos_OrderQuestions q where q.QuestionID = 181 and q.OrderID = p.OrderID)  + ' | ' +
(select max(Response) from qdos_OrderQuestions q where q.QuestionID = 185 and q.OrderID = p.OrderID)  + ' ' + (select max(Response) from qdos_OrderQuestions q where q.QuestionID = 191 and q.OrderID = p.OrderID) + ' ' + (select max(Response) from qdos_OrderQuestions q where q.QuestionID = 196 and q.OrderID = p.OrderID) 
end),
InsuredFullName = (select max(Response) from qdos_OrderQuestions q where q.QuestionID = 56 and q.OrderID = p.OrderID),
InsuredDOB = (select max(Response) from qdos_OrderQuestions q where q.QuestionID = 55 and q.OrderID = p.OrderID),
InsuredGender = (select max(Response) from qdos_OrderQuestions q where q.QuestionID = 57 and q.OrderID = p.OrderID),
o.Renewal, sp.Marketing, sp.How_Hear, sp.How_Hear_Other, wl.title as WhiteLabelName, c.CouponCode
from qdos_OrderPayments p 
left join qdos_PaymentTypes pt on p.PaymentTypeID = pt.PaymentTypeID
inner join qdos_orders o on p.OrderID = o.OrderID
inner join sf_user_profile_link pl on o.customerid = pl.user_id
inner join sf_sitefinity_profile sp on pl.profile_id = sp.id
left join qdos_WhiteLabels wl on wl.WhiteLabelID = sp.white_label_id
left join qdos_Coupons c on o.CouponID = c.CouponID
where 
o.ShopID = 1  
and ((@DateType = 1 and  p.PaymentAddedDate >=@DateFrom and p.PaymentAddedDate <=Dateadd(n,-1,Dateadd(d,1,@DateTo))) or
 (@DateType = 2 and  p.PaymentReceivedDate >=@DateFrom and p.PaymentReceivedDate <=Dateadd(n,-1,Dateadd(d,1,@DateTo))))
 and (@PaymentType = -1 or (@PaymentType = 1 and p.PaymentTypeID IN (1,2,3,4)) or (@PaymentType = 2 and p.PaymentTypeID IN (5,6)) )
 and  (@PaymentReceived = -1 or (@PaymentReceived = 0 and p.PaymentReceivedDate IS Null or (@PaymentReceived = 1 and p.PaymentReceivedDate IS Not Null)))
  and (@ProductsList = '' or o.ProductID in (Select IntValue from dbo.CsvToInt(@ProductsList)))


-- Turn NOCOUNT back OFF
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Comment: The code of stored procedure is not enough. Performance depends on many factors: the number of rows in tables, presence or not of indexes... Did you examine an execution plan?

Comment: Be ensure that all inner joins written first then left joins .

It improves performance because after inner join data is less then previous one but if u use left joins first it join with all records.

Comment: @NavneetVerma That is not true. Unless you use the query hint `FORCE ORDER`, SQL Server will perform the joins in whatever order it thinks is the most efficient.

Comment: You really need to post execution plans if you are asking questions about query tuning, as well as details of relevant indexes you have created. Given the number of conditions like this `(@PaymentType = -1 or (@PaymentType = 1 and p.PaymentTypeID IN (1,2,3,4))` I suspect parameter sniffing could be an issue. The query plan for a stored procedure is created based on the parameter passed when it is compiled, but since the best plan will depend on the parameter value, it is possible you are frequently getting suboptimal plans.

Comment: Is there any reason you run essentially the same query twice, once to get a count of results, and then only use this count to limit the results the next time you run the query? Finally, using `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is not good practice, you will get nondeterministic results.

Comment: Hi, i run the initial query as on page load i show the user the top 100 rows as a preview and then in need the virtual count to display actual total, ill have a look into execution plans.
Sometimes th query is very quick, say 10 seconds and sometimes 10 minutes, is this down to sql internally caching a certain query?

Comment: Sorry, missed that it was a different parameter in the `TOP()` clause. Yes, I suspect it will be the query plan caching if you get fluctuating performance. I'd try adding `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` after each of the queries.

Comment: ok i have looked into execution plans, first time i have dipped my toes in, all looking a bit complex, what am i specifically looking for, or how could i share the plan?

Comment: the most stand out object is a clustered index scan at 7%, this appears for all of my sub select statements

Comment: OK, used sql suggestions for creating indexes and seems much better, thanks for pointing me towards the execution plan..